# jq - parsing complex JSON into a string

Tags: json, parsing, jq

I'm trying to use `jq` to parse JSON that looks something like:

```
{
    "username": "billy",
    "hero": {
        "something": "goeshere"
    },
    "bumper": {
        "bumper2": {
            "bumper3": "splodge"
        }
    },
    "morgan": [{
        "abc": 123
    }, 2, 4, {
        "def": 567
    }],
    "password": "issilly"
}
```

into

```
request.username == 'billy' && request.hero.something == 'goeshere' && request.bumper.bumper2.bumper3 == 'splodge' && request.morgan[0].abc == 123 && request.morgan[1] == 2 && request.morgan[2] == 4 && request.morgan[3].def == 567 && request.password == 'issilly'
```

So far I've got to

```
jq '. | to_entries[] | "request.\(.key) == '\(.value)'"'
```

which gets me part of the way there, but I can't work out how to "walk down" into the deep-nested elements, nor how to join the strings produced into a single line delimited with ' && '

Comment: You want to create a query to get that as a JSON object?

Comment: Yep exactly - if it helps, I'm trying to programmatically define a test case around a given JSON payload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you output that is not quite what you posted, but should be good enough, given that JavaScript does not distinguish `foo.bar` and `foo["bar"]`.

```
jq -r '
  . as $data |
  [path(.. | 
    select(type != "object" and type != "array")
  )] |
  map(
    . as $path |
    map("[" + (. | tojson) + "]") |
    join("") |
    "request\(.) = \($data | getpath($path) | tojson)"
  ) |
  join(" && ")
' < test.json
```

Output:

```
request["username"] = "billy" &&
request["hero"]["something"] = "goeshere" &&
request["bumper"]["bumper2"]["bumper3"] = "splodge" &&
request["morgan"][0]["abc"] = 123 &&
request["morgan"][1] = 2 &&
request["morgan"][2] = 4 &&
request["morgan"][3]["def"] = 567 &&
request["password"] = "issilly"
```

Explanation: `..` gives us all values; but we want only the leaf values, so we filter out those that are arrays or objects. Then we get the array of paths using `[path()]`: this will be an array of arrays of path steps, like this: `[["username"], ["hero", "something"], ["bumper", "bumper2", "bumper3"], ["morgan", 0, "abc"]... ]` etc. Now for each path, we need to enclose each path step in brackets to get something that JavaScript can understand. `tojson` will give the exact thing that the brackets need, so that string keys of objects get quoted but the integral keys of arrays don't. We can now put together the equality expression: the left side needs a `request` prepended to the brackety path we constructed, while we can use `getpath` to get the value that should be on the right hand side (again using `tojson` to get the correct literal).

Answer (score 4):

`paths(scalars)` outputs arrays representing paths to strings and numbers in `.`, and using `getpath` you can get values at those paths. So all you need is a function that converts path representations to path expressions, like:

```
def pr2pe:
  reduce .[] as $n ([];
    if $n|type == "string"
    then . + [$n]
    elif $n|type == "number" and length
    then .[-1] += "[\($n)]"
    else error("invalid path representation")
    end) | join(".");
[ paths(scalars) as $p
  | "\($p | pr2pe) == \(getpath($p) | tojson)" ]
| join(" && ")
```

See it on [jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/rBIMcCEl0w)